# Zip code mismatching in google api

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm using google API service in my project, while doing some sample testing i have came across an issue with the below api service call,

"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geode/json?address=00210&sensor=true"

Which shows the Finland address but i want the information regarding the USA. How can i solve this problem? Is there anything which i need to pass like country code or something?

Comment: is 00210 a genuine american zip code?

Comment: USPS doesn't recognize this postal code as valid https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupResultsAction!input.action?resultMode=2&companyName=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=Select&urbanCode=&postalCode=00210&zip=

Comment: How can we handle the same zip codes in different country through google map api calls?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the suggested way to find a postal code in certain country is applying a component filtering that is described in the following document:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

You can create request like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A00210%7Ccountry%3AFI&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You can also check this in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DFI%26in_postal_code%3D00210

Hope it helps!