# google API geo coding using zip code not working

Tags: php, google-geocoding-api

Google maps geocoding API does not return results that google maps returns

```
$result_string = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($zip)."&sensor=false&mode=driving");

$result = json_decode($result_string, true);

$result1[]=$result['results'][0];
$result2[]=$result1[0]['geometry'];
$result3[]=$result2[0]['location'];

return $result3[0];
```

Comment: Can you paste `$result_string`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862745/google-geocode-api-longitude-and-latitude-unavailble-for-zip-96101

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493250/zip-code-mismatching-in-google-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501111/google-maps-api-query-with-only-zip-code-provides-incorrect-results

Answer (score 0):

Check below code i hope it helps..

```
<input type="button" onclick="GetLocation()" value="Get Location" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function GetLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
            } else {
                alert("Request failed.")
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```